# How can I recursively delete folder with a specific name with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, recursion, windows-7, directory

I can delete files with specific extensions in multiple folders with this:

```
Get-childitem * -include *.scc -recurse | remove-item
```

But I also need to delete folders with a specific name - in particular those that subversion creates (".svn" or "_svn") when you pull down files from a subversion repo.

Comment: For those who want to remove all `.svn` folders: perhaps `svn export` is of use to you. It will do a checkout but without adding the `.svn` folders.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This [one](http://www.tigraine.at/2009/11/24/removing-svn-folders-with-powershell/) should do it:

```
get-childitem -Include .svn -Recurse -force | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

[Other](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/80403-pecursive-delete-implementation-powershell.html) version:

```
$fso = New-Object -com "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
$folder = $fso.GetFolder("C:\Test\")

foreach ($subfolder in $folder.SubFolders)
{
    If ($subfolder.Name -like "*.svn")
    {
        remove-item $subfolder.Path -Verbose
    }       
}
```

Comment: You might get "Cannot remove item directory not empty" kind of errors on the first few times. But when you keep trying the above command, it works.

Answer (score 16):

I tend to avoid the `-Include` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` as it is slower than `-Filter`. However in this instance (since it can't be expressed as a `-Filter`), this is what I would use:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Include .svn,_svn -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

or if typing this at the prompt:

```
ls . -inc .svn,_svn -r -fo | ri -r -fo
```

Comment: Not a typo but the wildcard character `?` wasn't working as I expected.  It should have matched both `_` and `.` but it wasn't matching the `.`.  Go figure.

Comment: I'm confused @Keith.  You said you avoid -include, but that's what you used.

Comment: I said I "tend" to avoid -include for the reason stated above. However, if you need to filter based on several different wildcard specs, -filter won't handle that.  So using -include should be no slower than piping through Where-Object to filter on the filename.

Comment: @MikeShepard (and Keith) I took the liberty of editing in some of Keith's comment into the body of the answer as it had me puzzling too!  I guess best to leave both comments (and this) for future generations...

Comment: I got errors using this, presumably because it tries to call `Get-ChildItem` on folders that are already deleted, so I added `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the `ri` or `Remove-Item` command to mute it.

Comment: This worked good for me.  It also solved how to specify multiple directories in a single invocation.  Finally, it helped me understand the difference between `-Filter` and `-Include`, so now I know when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 14):

### For fast deletion, use -Filter

To recursively delete **a folder with a specific name** `-Filter` is significantly faster than `-Include`.

So, for visibility, here is the faster version of @Keith's answer:

Fully typed-out:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter .svn -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Short version:

```
ls . -filter .svn -r -fo | ri -r -fo
```

Comment: hm - is there also a version which outputs the paths deleted? just so i know it works and all.

Comment: Just used it for deleting git folders in an archive. worked perfectly. thanks. So to remove .git folders recursively run `ls . -filter .git -r -fo  | ri -r -fo`